# define a policy for Comments deleting that checks comment author or post author (laravel)

Tags: laravel, comments, acl, posts, policy

How can you enable both the author of the post and the author of a comment to delete it?
I mean, the author of the posts can delete every comment under his posts, while the author of a comment can delete only the comments he left.

So far I have a commentPolicy class that works like this:

```
class CommentPolicy
{
    public function deleteComment(User $user, Comment $comment)
    {

        return $user->id === $comment->user_id;

    }

}
```

of course this works for the author of the comment. What I'm thinking is I should enable the author of the posts to delete comments in the postPolicy class. What I have there is:

```
class PostPolicy

{

    public function seePostOptions(User $user, Post $post)
    {
        return $user->id === $post->user_id;
    }


}
```

Right now the author of the post can see some options to edit / delete / comment on post.
I was thinking maybe I should just put two `@can('deleteComment', $c)<>delete button<>@endcan` and `@can('seePostOptions' $i)<>delete button<>@endcan` but this will result in double button for all those comments left by the author of the post under his post.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is using the @else directive like this:

```
@can('deleteComment', $c)
<p>delete</p>
@else
@can('seePostOptions', $i)
<p>delete</p>
@endcan
@endcan
```